# Cron error while executing magemonitoring_uberdog:

Tags: error, cron, catalog-price-rules

I´m still figuring out how to not "reset" all catalog price rules every night. 
As far as i read now the cron.php should be executed every night - it still isnt working.

When I´m executing the cron.php I´m receiving 27 Emails:

```
Cron error while executing magemonitoring_uberdog:

exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Too late for the schedule.' in /www/htdocs/***/***/***/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /www/htdocs/***/***/***/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(47): Mage::throwException('Too late for th...')
#1 /www/htdocs/***/***/***/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#2 /www/htdocs/***/***/***/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#3 /www/htdocs/***/***/***/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#4 /www/htdocs/***/***/***/cron.php(74): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#5 {main}
```

All these 27 E-Mails got this exact content. I´ve googled it - seems no one got this problem. Could someone tell me anything about that? I dont even know what to ask exactly. Any tip would help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, this error is from AOE Scheduler extension. If you open the reviews of this extension - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html and go to 2nd review on page 3 (Bug Found by wingsryder on February 12, 2014) - there is a solution:

> in class class Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer extends Mage_Cron_Model_Observer
>   Fix : we need to add
>   const XML_PATH_SCHEDULE_LIFETIME = 'system/cron/schedule_lifetime';

Comment: Thanks very much. There were much more errors after solving this problem but: first error (as explained) solved the way you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Your cron.php file should be run much more frequently than nightly. I would say the reason you are getting this is that the job in question is scheduled to run every hour or so, when you run the cron.php it will schedule future jobs to run, by the time the cron runs again the next night most of the scheduled jobs would of been missed.

I would suggest setting up your cron so that cron.sh (not cron.php) is called every 15 (or even 5) minutes. Magento internally will take care of the scheduling so not all tasks will run that often.